# Exposing non-empty docker container directories to host

Tags: docker

Since one can have a nice Docker container to run an entire build in, it would be fantastic if the tools used by the container to build and run the code would be accessible to the host.

Imagine the following use-case:

1. Imagine that you're developing a Java application using OpenJDK 12 and Maven 3.6.1 in order to build, run all tests and package the entire application into an executable .jar file.
2. You create a Docker container that serves as a "build container". This container has OpenJDK 12 and Maven 3.6.1 installed and can be used to build and package your entire application (you could use it locally, during development and you could also use it on a build-server, triggering the build whenever code changes are pushed).
3. Now, you actually want to start writing some code... naturally, you'll go ahead and open your project in your favorite IDE (IntelliJ IDEA?), configure the project SDK and whatever else needs to be configured and start rocking!

   Would it not be fantastic to be able to tell IntelliJ (Eclipse, NetBeans, VSCode, whatever...) to simply use the same tools with the same versions as the build container is using? Sure, you could tell your IDE to delegate building to the "build container" (Docker), but without setting the appropriate "Project SDK" (and other configs), then you'd be "coding in the dark"... you'd be losing out on almost all the benefits of using a powerful IDE for development. No code hinting, no static code analysis, etc. etc. etc. Your cool and fancy IDE is in essence reduced to a simple text editor that can at least trigger a full-build by calling your build container.

   In order to keep benefiting from the many IDE features, you'll need to install OpenJDK 12, Maven 3.6.1 and whatever else you need (in essence, the same tools you have already spent time configuring your Docker image with) and then tell the IDE that "these" are the tool it should use for "this" project.

It's unfortunately too easy to accidentally install the wrong version of the tool on your host (locally), that could potentially lead to the "it works on my machine" syndrome. Sure, you'd still spot problems later down the road once the project is built using the appropriate tools and versions by the build container/server, but... not to mention how annoying things can become when having to maintain an entire zoo of tools an their versions on your machine (+ potentially having to deal with all kind of funky incompatibilities or interactions between all the tools) when you happen to work on multiple projects (one project needs JDK 8, the other JDK 11, the other uses Gradle, not Maven, then you also need Node 10, Angular 5, but also 6, etc. etc. etc.).

So far, I only came across all kind of funky workarounds, but no "nice" solution. The most tolerable I found so far is to manually expose (copy) the tools from the container on the host machine (e.g.: define a volume shared by both and then execute a manual script that would not copy the tools from the container into the shared volume directory so that the host can access them as well)... while this would work, it unfortunately involves a manual step, which means that whenever the container is updated (e.g.: new versions of certain tools are used or even additional, completely new ones) then the developer needs to remember to perform the manual copying step (execute whatever script explicitly) in order have all the latest and greatest stuff available to the host once again (of course, this could potentially mean updating IDE configs as - but this - version upgrades at least - can be mitigated to a large degree by having the tools reside at non-version specific paths).

Does anyone have some idea how to achieve this? VM's are out of the question and would seem like an overkill... I don't see why accessing Docker container resources in a *read-only* fashion should not be possible and *reuse and reference* appropriate tooling during both development and build.

Comment: Iam currently thinking of the same solution. I heard that EclipseChe (runs in a web browser) can access your project workspace which is in a container. Then you could directly modifing your code, etc. But I am currently not so far to share any expirience.